# Java repeated Cartesian product and combinations

Tags: java, python

Is there an equivalent to python's product and combination functions?

Or in other words, given a set of Integers, and REPEAT number of times to repeat,
is there a way to create a list of lists or array of arrays or something of this sort that contains all the ways to choose REPEAT objects from the set with or without choosing the same element twice.
The main issue is that the number of repetition times is not known during compilation time.

Example of combination (with choosing twice):
input [1,2,3,4,5] 3
output [[1,1,1], [1,1,2] ... ]

Example of product (without choosing twice):
input [1,2,3,4,5] 3
output [[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,2,5] ... ]

Comment: check out combinatorics lib: https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib

Comment: This looks like a great library @RC, you should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Posting @RC's comment as an answer for others to find [this library](http://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib).

Perhaps there is something a more standard way or a simple code to do it in java (which people will be able to copy and change without importing a package just for it).
But anyway, [this](http://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib) seems like a good library to do just that.